# Android: How to dynamically change the Layout of my ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a viewpager that contains of pages. Both are basically exactly the same, only one is with different drawables. So all I need to do is change the drawables when page two is selected, and change it back when page one is selected. I got this all to work with ONE layout, but I couldn't find out where to change the drawables. This is my code so fare:

```
private void initViewPager()
{
    ViewPager _viewpager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
    _viewpager.Adapter = new FragmentAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
}

  public class FragmentAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        public FragmentAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fm) : base(fm)
        { 

        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return 2; }
        }

        public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {
            return new LayoutFragment();
        }
    }


    public class LayoutFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Viewpage1, container, false);    

            return view; 
        }
    }
```

I'm inflating "Viewpage1". This layout contains my xml that, when page two is selected needs to have changed drawables ( just the image of 6 buttons).

How would I implement that into my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps

1.Create one more fragment like you have done for `LayoutFragment`. Say `NewLayoutFragment`

2.Pass your new layout to the newly created fragment.

```
public class NewLayoutFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Viewpage2, container, false);    // Viewpage2 is your new layout file with 6 buttons.

        return view; 
    }
}
```

3.Put a `switch` statement in your `getItem()` method of your Adapter and call the new Fragment instance in the second case. Like this:

```
public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        switch(position){
            case 0:
            return new LayoutFragment();

            case 1:
            return new NewLayoutFragment(); // this is your new Fragment with new layout.
        }

    }
```

I hope this should work. :) Happy coding.

Comment: Hey thank you so much! That was it! Just onw more thing:
Now, when I am in my second layout - I want my buttons to be clickable as well - but they have to lead to another activity now compared to where they led to when on page one of the viewpager. Where do I implement my buttons? THANKS AGAIN! :=)

Comment: Because I just relalized, that I cannont init my buttons since they come from another layout file. I hope you understand what I mean thanks :)

Comment: Hey, glad I could help. You can set `onClickListener()`s to your buttons in your `NewFragment` class and call your desired Activity/Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You should set a PageChangeListener to your viewpager like this :

```
_viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {


            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) { }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) { }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

             switch (position) {

                 //put your logic code here to change what's you want in your layout 


            }

        });
```